# How to pass optional class with array

Tags: swiftui, binding

I have a core data pair of entities with a relationship, basically a master/detail arrangement in a true database.  I'm trying to get the following code to compile and can't figure out the binding/syntax to make it possible to directly change the attributes in the detail items. Is this even possible in SwiftUI? I can't change any of the optionals since I need them for the way this app must operate.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Item: NSManagedObject, Identifiable
{
    @NSManaged public var sequence: Int
    @NSManaged public var txt: String
}


class Stuff: NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var listitems: NSSet?
    
    public var listitemsArray: [Item]
    {
        let set = listitems as? Set<Item> ?? []
        return set.sorted
        {
            $0.sequence < $1.sequence
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var stuff: Stuff?
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            if let stuff = stuff
            {
                ForEach($stuff.listitemsArray)
                {
                    $x in
                    ItemView(item: $x)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View
{
    @Binding var item: Item
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            TextField("Item...", text: $item.txt)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each CoreData object is an `ObservableObject` they need to be wrapped in an `@ObservedObject`, all instances of `Item` and `Stuff`. `@Binding` and `@State` are only for value type (`String`, `Int`, etc) not `ObservableObject`s

Comment: Once you wrap all the `ObservableObject`s property you can search in SO for the exact error you will get for the `Binding` `String` or `Binding` `Int` error there are many solutions on SO to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the detail View use `@ObservedObject var item: Item`

And you need `@FetchRequest` in the master view. I recommend creating a new project in Xcode and checking the Core Data box to learn the structure.